# CSS Submenu Mistake: ul#[class] -> position: absolute; No overlap or wrong menu width

Tags: html, css, navigation, position, absolute

I am new here and this is my first question so please have mercy on me and my broken english ;)

I have a mistake on my html navi. I followed multiple guides and now I have the following problem: If I add the command `position: absolute;` on my subnavi element, it is possible to overlap following content, but the submenu items are not in the same size as the main menu! If I delete it, the size is right, but I have no overlap!

Pls guys, I need your help, cause this projekt got a grade and it must be finished until Monday!

R. Geist

Scrennshots of my results:
[Frame with "postion: absolute"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9uXk.jpg)
[Frame without "postion: absolute"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlBZu.jpg)

And my Code:

```css
/* CSS Style für Kletterwelt - Allgemeine Inhalte v1.01 vom 17.06.2017*/


/* Allgemeine Daten & Einstellungen */
*
{
 margin:  0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body
{
 /* Für den Gesamten Inhalt gilt */
 width:   90%;
 margin:   auto;
 
 /* Für den Text des gesamten Inhaltes gilt */
 font-family: arial;
}

header img
{
 width: 100%;
}


/* Navi */
ul.navi
{
 list-style-type:none;
}

ul#hauptmenu li
{
 width:   19%;   /* Aufteilung der Hauptmenüpunkte in relative Größe */
 text-align:  center;
 position:  relativ; /* Untermenüs werden relativ zu ihrem Hauptmenüpunkt zugeordnet */
 float:    left;
 margin-right: 4px;
}

ul#hauptmenu a
{
 text-decoration: none; /* Entfernt Unterstriche der Links */
 display:   block; /* gesamtes Listenelement wird zum anklickbaren Button, nicht nur das Wort */
 height:    40px;
 line-height:  40px; /* Wenn Wert mit "height" identisch ist, ist Text vertikal zentriert */
 background-color: #333333;
 color:    white;
 font-weight:  bold;
 border:    2px solid #333333;
 border-radius:  5px;
}

ul#untermenu li
{
 width: 100%; /* Untermenüpunkte sind relativ! Also sollen sie die voll zur verfügung stehende Länge nutzen */
}

ul#hauptmenu li:hover > a
{
 background-color: #777777; /* markiert Buttons übergeordneter Menüs UND den Button, über den man hovert, grau */
}

ul#hauptmenu li:hover a:hover
{
 background-color: #FF0000; /* markiert Button, über den man hovert, rot (überschreibt Definition)*/
}

ul#hauptmenu ul#untermenu
{
 display: none; /* Untermenüpunkte standardmäßig ausblenden*/
 /* position: absolute; /* HERE!!! WHY?! */
}

ul#hauptmenu li:hover #untermenu
{
 display: block; /* beim Hovern über übergeordneten Menü, soll das untergeordnete eingeblendet werden */
 z-index: 500; /* Untermenüpunkte werden über dem Content angezeigt (Ebenen-technisch) */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">
<head>
 <title>testnavi</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="./bilder/icon.ico"> 
 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <meta name="Florian Zimmermann, Rudolf Geist & Thomas Kretzer" content="HTML-Projekt: Kletterwelt">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/CWAllgemeinStyle.css">
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/testc.css"> -->

</head>

<body>  
 <header>  
  <img src="./bilder/headerbild.jpg">
 
  <!--Hinweis zu Navis! Untermenüs stehen innerhalb der Klammern eines Listenelements li !!! -->
  <ul class="navi" id="hauptmenu">
   <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
    <ul class="navi" id="untermenu">
     <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SCHWIERIGKEITSGRADE</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SICHERUNGSGERÄTE</a>
    <ul class="navi" id="untermenu">
     <li><a href="#geräteart1">DINGER</a></li>
     <li><a href="#geräteart2">TEILE </a></li>
    </ul>
   </li> 
   <li><a href="#">ALLGEMEINES</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <img src="./bilder/headerbild.jpg">
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:
My index.html will be in a projekt-folder. In this folder will be a "css"-folder, where my "CWAllgemeinStyle.css" lie.

Comment: I tested some more and got a ugly workarround:

I played with the following comand and its nearly ok:

ul#hauptmenu ul#untermenu
{
 display: none;  /* Untermenüpunkte standardmäßig ausblenden*/
 position: absolute;
 width:  17%;
}

but trust me, i have no idea why this worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were spelt your style wrong on `ul#hauptmenu li`. It should be `position:relative` not  `position:relativ`. This is required because otherwise your position absolute `ul#hauptmenu ul#untermenu` element would not be position relative to `ul#hauptmenu li`.

I have added `position:absolute` back to `ul#hauptmenu ul#untermenu` to take it out of the flow of the website so it doesn't push your content down. I have also added `width:100%` so it expands to the width of the parent `li`.

```css
/* CSS Style für Kletterwelt - Allgemeine Inhalte v1.01 vom 17.06.2017*/


/* Allgemeine Daten & Einstellungen */
*
{
 margin:  0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body
{
 /* Für den Gesamten Inhalt gilt */
 width:   90%;
 margin:   auto;
 
 /* Für den Text des gesamten Inhaltes gilt */
 font-family: arial;
}

header img
{
 width: 100%;
}


/* Navi */
ul.navi
{
 list-style-type:none;
}

ul#hauptmenu li
{
 width:   19%;   /* Aufteilung der Hauptmenüpunkte in relative Größe */
 text-align:  center;
  /* This style was spent wrong. You spelt it relativ */
 position:  relative; /* Untermenüs werden relativ zu ihrem Hauptmenüpunkt zugeordnet */
 float:    left;
 margin-right: 4px;
}

ul#hauptmenu a
{
 text-decoration: none; /* Entfernt Unterstriche der Links */
 display:   block; /* gesamtes Listenelement wird zum anklickbaren Button, nicht nur das Wort */
 height:    40px;
 line-height:  40px; /* Wenn Wert mit "height" identisch ist, ist Text vertikal zentriert */
 background-color: #333333;
 color:    white;
 font-weight:  bold;
 border:    2px solid #333333;
 border-radius:  5px;
}

ul#untermenu li
{
 width: 100%; /* Untermenüpunkte sind relativ! Also sollen sie die voll zur verfügung stehende Länge nutzen */
}

ul#hauptmenu li:hover > a
{
 background-color: #777777; /* markiert Buttons übergeordneter Menüs UND den Button, über den man hovert, grau */
}

ul#hauptmenu li:hover a:hover
{
 background-color: #FF0000; /* markiert Button, über den man hovert, rot (überschreibt Definition)*/
}

ul#hauptmenu ul#untermenu
{
 display: none; /* Untermenüpunkte standardmäßig ausblenden*/
  /* Position absolute required to take it out of the flow of the website so it stops below content being push down */
 position: absolute;
  /* Applied width 100% to it expands to the width of the parent li. */
  width:100%;
}

ul#hauptmenu li:hover #untermenu
{
 display: block; /* beim Hovern über übergeordneten Menü, soll das untergeordnete eingeblendet werden */
 z-index: 500; /* Untermenüpunkte werden über dem Content angezeigt (Ebenen-technisch) */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">
<head>
 <title>testnavi</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="./bilder/icon.ico"> 
 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <meta name="Florian Zimmermann, Rudolf Geist & Thomas Kretzer" content="HTML-Projekt: Kletterwelt">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/CWAllgemeinStyle.css">
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/testc.css"> -->

</head>

<body>  
 <header>  
  <img src="./bilder/headerbild.jpg">
 
  <!--Hinweis zu Navis! Untermenüs stehen innerhalb der Klammern eines Listenelements li !!! -->
  <ul class="navi" id="hauptmenu">
   <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
    <ul class="navi" id="untermenu">
     <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SCHWIERIGKEITSGRADE</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SICHERUNGSGERÄTE</a>
    <ul class="navi" id="untermenu">
     <li><a href="#geräteart1">DINGER</a></li>
     <li><a href="#geräteart2">TEILE </a></li>
    </ul>
   </li> 
   <li><a href="#">ALLGEMEINES</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <img src="./bilder/headerbild.jpg">
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```